# RNG hidden field parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a registration form and I am taking the users input and passing the information to a payment website. The payment website has several hidden fields so it can distinguish each individual user as unique instead of relying on a unique name provided by the user. That's what the "unique_id" field is and I want a random number to be the parameter. How would I make this work so every time a user clicks the button that this code is attached to, it executes the RNG and passes that number to the external payment website?

...

```
    protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
Random randnum = new Random();
int num = randnum.Next();
        {
            NameValueCollection PostFields = new NameValueCollection();
            PostFields.Add("LMID", "345573");
            PostFields.Add("unique_id", RANDOM NUMBER HEEDS TO GO HERE);
            PostFields.Add("sTotal", "150.00");
            PostFields.Add("webTitle", "Conference");
            PostFields.Add("Trans_Desc", "Conference Registration");
            PostFields.Add("contact_info", "Contact admin");
            PostFields.Add("BILL_CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME", labelFirstName.Text);
            PostFields.Add("BILL_CUSTOMER_LASTNAME", labelLastName.Text);
            PostFields.Add("BILL_ADDRESS1", labelAddress.Text);
            PostFields.Add("BILL_CITY", labelCity.Text);
            PostFields.Add("BILL_STATE", labelState.Text);
            PostFields.Add("BILL_ZIP", labelZip.Text);
            PostFields.Add("BILL_CUSTOMER_PHONE", labelTelephone.Text);
            PostFields.Add("BILL_CUSTOMER_EMAIL", labelEmail.Text);
            RedirectAndPOST(this.Page, "payment website url", PostFields);
        }
```

...

Comment: Have you tried `num.ToString()` ?

Comment: Yeah it's giving me an overload error

Comment: Post the code that is giving you the overload error, and the exact error message and exception type you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
    Random random = new Random(); int num = random.Next();

    NameValueCollection PostFields = new NameValueCollection();
    PostFields.Add("LMID", "093204"); 
    PostFields.Add("unique_id", num.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks that's what StarPilot had said and it worked after I tweaked some of my code that was below what I posted.